# Некоторые SVG не воспроизводят анимацию

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg

На сайте есть карусель ***Owl-carousel***.
Написал скрипт, что если переключать слайдеры карусели, то `SVG` картинка должна воспроизводиться заново.

> Копирование SVG, вставка SVG и удаление последней SVG.

Проблема в том, что первая `SVG` в первом слайдере воспроизводится нормально, вторая `SVG` во втором слайдере тоже нормально работает, остальные не хотят воспроизводиться. Просто появляются без анимации. Код прилагаю

> Чтобы моя страница нормально отображалась, в настройках выберите
>   Bottom Results в JSFiddle

```js
$("#top-owl-carousel").on('changed.owl.carousel', function(event) {

  var mySvg1Anim = $("#svg1");
  var mySvg1AnimCopy = mySvg1Anim.clone(true);
  var mySvg2Anim = $("#svg2");
  var mySvg2AnimCopy = mySvg2Anim.clone(true);
  var mySvg3Anim = $("#svg3");
  var mySvg3AnimCopy = mySvg3Anim.clone(true);
  var mySvg4Anim = $("#svg4");
  var mySvg4AnimCopy = mySvg4Anim.clone(true);
  var mySvg5Anim = $("#svg5");
  var mySvg5AnimCopy = mySvg5Anim.clone(true);

  mySvg1Anim.before(mySvg1AnimCopy);
  mySvg1Anim.last().remove();


  mySvg2Anim.before(mySvg2AnimCopy);
  mySvg2Anim.last().remove();


  mySvg3Anim.before(mySvg3AnimCopy);
  mySvg3Anim.last().remove();


  mySvg4Anim.before(mySvg4AnimCopy);
  mySvg4Anim.last().remove();


  mySvg5Anim.before(mySvg5AnimCopy);
  mySvg5Anim.last().remove();
});
$("#top-owl-carousel").owlCarousel({
  items: 1,
  smartSpeed: 1000,
  loop: true,
  mouseDrag: true,
  touchDrag: true,
  nav: true,
  dots: true,
  autoplay: true,
  autoplayTimeout: 100000,
  autoplayHoverPause: true,
});
```

```css
.terentev-code-1-list #top-owl-carousel {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.terentev-code-1-list #top-owl-carousel .owl-dots {
  position: absolute;
  top: 360px;
  right: 50px;
}

.terentev-code-1-list #top-owl-carousel .owl-prev span {
  position: absolute;
  top: 150px;
  left: 20px;
  font-size: 40pt;
  color: #a8a8a8;
  z-index: 20;
}

.terentev-code-1-list #top-owl-carousel .owl-next span {
  position: absolute;
  top: 150px;
  right: 20px;
  font-size: 40pt;
  color: #a8a8a8;
  z-index: 20;
}

.terentev-code-1-list #top-owl-carousel .slide {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  padding: 0 60px 20px 60px;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  color: white;
  font-weight: 1000;
}

.terentev-code-1-list #top-owl-carousel .slide h2 {
  font-size: 30pt;
}

.terentev-code-1-list #top-owl-carousel .slide .description {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 60%;
}

.terentev-code-1-list #top-owl-carousel .slide .img {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
  -ms-flex-pack: center;
  justify-content: center;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  position: relative;
  width: 40%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.terentev-code-1-list #top-owl-carousel .slide .img #svg1 {
  width: 200%;
}

.terentev-code-1-list #top-owl-carousel .slide .img #svg2 {
  width: 200%;
}

.terentev-code-1-list #top-owl-carousel .slide .img #svg3 {
  width: 200%;
}

.terentev-code-1-list #top-owl-carousel .slide .img .svgObject {
  width: auto;
  margin: auto;
  position: absolute;
  top: 25%;
  left: 25%;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
  -ms-flex-pack: center;
  justify-content: center;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.terentev-code-1-list #top-owl-carousel .slide button {
  color: white;
  border: 1px white solid;
  background: transparent;
  padding: 10px 15px 10px 15px;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.4s ease;
  transition: all 0.4s ease;
}

.terentev-code-1-list #top-owl-carousel .slide button:hover {
  color: white;
  background: transparent;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 15px 20px 15px 20px;
}

.terentev-code-1-list #top-owl-carousel .slide-1 {
  background: #36d1dc;
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right top, from(#30b7c1), to(#5b86e5));
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #30b7c1, #5b86e5);
  height: 450px;
  width: 100vw;
}

.terentev-code-1-list #top-owl-carousel .slide-2 {
  background: #1c92d2;
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right top, from(#5b86e5), to(#7f51a7));
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #5b86e5, #7f51a7);
  height: 450px;
  width: 100vw;
}

.terentev-code-1-list #top-owl-carousel .slide-3 {
  background: #ef3b36;
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right top, from(#7f51a7), to(#355C7D));
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #7f51a7, #355C7D);
  height: 450px;
  width: 100vw;
}

.terentev-code-1-list #top-owl-carousel .slide-4 {
  background: #4ac29a;
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right top, from(#355C7D), to(#C06C84));
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #355C7D, #C06C84);
  height: 450px;
  width: 100vw;
}

.terentev-code-1-list #top-owl-carousel .slide-5 {
  background: #ef3b36;
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right top, from(#C06C84), to(#30b7c1));
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #C06C84, #30b7c1);
  height: 450px;
  width: 100vw;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.3.4/owl.carousel.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.3.4/assets/owl.carousel.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.3.4/assets/owl.theme.default.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="terentev-code-1-list">
  <div class="slider-top owl-carousel owl-theme" id="top-owl-carousel">
    <div class="slide slide-1">
      <div class="bottom-particles">

      </div>
      <div class="description">
        <div>
          <h2>
            ЦИФРОВЫЕ БИЛБОРДЫ<br> НОВОГОДНИЙ PRE-SALE
          </h2><br>
          <h4>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Cupiditate, qui! Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Itaque quidem nesciunt rerum cum numquam vero repudiandae optio nostrum incidunt reprehenderit.
          </h4><br>
          <button>Подробнее</button>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="img">
        <svg id="svg1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" style="position:relative" class="svg" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin meet" viewBox="-30 0 500 500">
    <set id="b" attributeName="visibility" begin="0s" dur="1s" to="hidden" xlink:href="#a" />
    <g id="a" fill="none" stroke="#fff" stroke-width="2">
        <path stroke-dasharray="540" d="M0 0h180v90H0z">
            <animate attributeName="stroke-dashoffset" begin="b.end" calcMode="linear" dur="1s" values="540; 0" />
        </path>
        <path stroke-dasharray="516" d="M5 5h170v80H5z">
            <animate fill="remove" attributeName="stroke-dashoffset" begin="b.end" calcMode="linear" dur="1s" repeatCount="1" values="516; 0" />
        </path>
        <path stroke-dasharray="100" d="M85 90v100">
            <animate fill="remove" attributeName="stroke-dashoffset" begin="b.end" calcMode="linear" dur="1s" repeatCount="1" values="100; 0" />
        </path>
        <path stroke-dasharray="100" d="M95 90v100">
            <animate fill="remove" attributeName="stroke-dashoffset" begin="b.end" calcMode="linear" dur="1s" repeatCount="1" values="100; 0" />
        </path>
        <path stroke-dasharray="150" d="M75 190h30v5H75v-5z">
            <animate fill="freese" attributeName="stroke-dashoffset" begin="b.end" calcMode="linear" dur="1s" repeatCount="1" values="150; 0" />
        </path>
    </g>
</svg>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="slide slide-2">
      <div class="description">
        <div>
          <h2>
            ЦИФРОВЫЕ БИЛБОРДЫ<br> НОВОГОДНИЙ PRE-SALE
          </h2><br>
          <h4>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Cupiditate, qui! Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Itaque quidem nesciunt rerum cum numquam vero repudiandae optio nostrum incidunt reprehenderit.
          </h4><br>
          <button>Подробнее</button>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="img">
        <svg id="svg2" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" style="position:relative" class="svg" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin meet" viewBox="-30 0 500 500"><set id="b" attributeName="visibility" begin="0s" dur="1s" to="hidden" xlink:href="#a"/><g id="a" fill="none" stroke="#fff" stroke-width="2"><path stroke-dasharray="540" d="M0 0h180v90H0z"><animate attributeName="stroke-dashoffset" begin="b.end" calcMode="linear" dur="1s" values="540; 0"/></path><path stroke-dasharray="516" d="M5 5h170v80H5z"><animate fill="remove" attributeName="stroke-dashoffset" begin="b.end" calcMode="linear" dur="1s" repeatCount="1" values="516; 0"/></path><path stroke-dasharray="100" d="M85 90v100"><animate fill="remove" attributeName="stroke-dashoffset" begin="b.end" calcMode="linear" dur="1s" repeatCount="1" values="100; 0"/></path><path stroke-dasharray="100" d="M95 90v100"><animate fill="remove" attributeName="stroke-dashoffset" begin="b.end" calcMode="linear" dur="1s" repeatCount="1" values="100; 0"/></path><path stroke-dasharray="150" d="M75 190h30v5H75v-5z"><animate fill="freese" attributeName="stroke-dashoffset" begin="b.end" calcMode="linear" dur="1s" repeatCount="1" values="150; 0"/></path></g></svg>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="slide slide-3">
      <div class="description">
        <div>
          <h2>
            ЦИФРОВЫЕ БИЛБОРfgfДЫ<br> НОВОГОДНИЙ PRE-SALE
          </h2><br>
          <h4>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Cupiditate, qui! Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Itaque quidem nesciunt rerum cum numquam vero repudiandae optio nostrum incidunt reprehenderit.
          </h4><br>
          <button>Подробнее</button>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="img">
        <svg id="svg3" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" style="position:relative" class="svg" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin meet" viewBox="-30 0 500 500"><set id="b" attributeName="visibility" begin="0s" dur="1s" to="hidden" xlink:href="#a"/><g id="a" fill="none" stroke="#fff" stroke-width="2"><path stroke-dasharray="540" d="M0 0h180v90H0z"><animate attributeName="stroke-dashoffset" begin="b.end" calcMode="linear" dur="1s" values="540; 0"/></path><path stroke-dasharray="516" d="M5 5h170v80H5z"><animate fill="remove" attributeName="stroke-dashoffset" begin="b.end" calcMode="linear" dur="1s" repeatCount="1" values="516; 0"/></path><path stroke-dasharray="100" d="M85 90v100"><animate fill="remove" attributeName="stroke-dashoffset" begin="b.end" calcMode="linear" dur="1s" repeatCount="1" values="100; 0"/></path><path stroke-dasharray="100" d="M95 90v100"><animate fill="remove" attributeName="stroke-dashoffset" begin="b.end" calcMode="linear" dur="1s" repeatCount="1" values="100; 0"/></path><path stroke-dasharray="150" d="M75 190h30v5H75v-5z"><animate fill="freese" attributeName="stroke-dashoffset" begin="b.end" calcMode="linear" dur="1s" repeatCount="1" values="150; 0"/></path></g></svg>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="slide slide-4">
      <div class="description">
        <div>
          <h2>
            ЦИФРОВЫЕ БИЛБОРДЫ<br> НОВОГОДНИЙ PRE-SALE
          </h2><br>
          <h4>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Cupiditate, qui! Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Itaque quidem nesciunt rerum cum numquam vero repudiandae optio nostrum incidunt reprehenderit.
          </h4><br>
          <button>Подробнее</button>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="img">
        <object data="img/city.svg" type="image/svg+xml" id="svg4" class="svgObject"></object>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="slide slide-5">
      <div class="description">
        <div>
          <h2>
            ЦИФРОВЫЕ БИЛБОРДЫ<br> НОВОГОДНИЙ PRE-SALE
          </h2><br>
          <h4>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Cupiditate, qui! Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Itaque quidem nesciunt rerum cum numquam vero repudiandae optio nostrum incidunt reprehenderit.
          </h4><br>
          <button>Подробнее</button>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="img">
        <object data="img/city.svg" type="image/svg+xml" id="svg5" class="svgObject"></object>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я нашел решение, написал скрипт

```js
$("#top-owl-carousel").on('translated.owl.carousel', function(event){
        $(this).find(".active #svg1, #svg2, #svg3, #svg4, #svg5").css("display","none");
        $(this).find(".active #svg1").css("display","block");
        $(this).find(".active #svg2").css("display","block");
        $(this).find(".active #svg3").css("display","block");
        $(this).find(".active #svg4").css("display","block");
        $(this).find(".active #svg5").css("display","block");
    });
    $("#top-owl-carousel").on('changed.owl.carousel', function(event){
        $(this).find(".active #svg1").css("display","none");
    });
```